# Mitzvas Kesivas Sefer Torah

Tags: halacha, writing-printing, transactions, sefer-torah

If you purchase a finished Sefer Torah are you Yotzei the Mitzva of Kesivas Sefer Torah?

Comment: http://forumpics.a7.org/?file=20121008231302.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a *machlokes* (dispute among) [*rishonim*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rishonim). See [a talk by Rabbi Josh Flug](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/724507/Rabbi_Josh_Flug/The_Mitzvah_of_Writing_a_Sefer_Torah), and the sources he cites, if you're interested in the *machlokes*, but I'll note that among Rabbi Flug's points are that *Rashi* holds purchasing suffices and that *Rambam* seems to hold it does not; [CYLOR](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/CYLOR) if you're interested in the practical *halacha*.